# What is the best way to format LaTeX source for the Kindle?

Tags: latex, kindle

I am trying to format my book for a Kindle 3. I'm writing the book using LaTeX. I am ok with transferring the file in PDF format but I need it formatted to be small.

I have tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,b7paper]{book}
\usepackage[top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm, left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm]{geometry}
```

But this is too small. I have also tried something like:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=9cm, paperheight=12cm, top=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm, bottom=1.5cm, includefoot]{geometry}
```

But that doesn't work well either. Has anyone found a good way to format a LaTeX PDF for the Kindle? (Not the big DX version.)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16735/latex-options-for-kindle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be much more than you need, but it's worth pointing out that there's a much more comprehensive answer over on [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16735/latex-options-for-kindle)

Answer (score 7):

This works well. I found it important to remove paper size from the dvips command. Forgetting to adjust that setting through me off for a while.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=9cm, paperheight=12cm, top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm, left=0.0cm, right=0.5cm]{geometry}
\special{papersize=9cm,12cm}
```

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you convert the LaTeX to HTML and create a Mobipocket document from that?  That way, the Kindle will be able to reflow the document, which it cannot do if you load it in PDF form.

Comment: I find that the PDF format looks better than books converted to HTML. Particularly with math and postscript drawings via the pstricks package. It is, however, a viable alternative for simple documents. It has the advantage of being able to be converted to the native Kindle book format.